# How to automatically import CSV into Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I get a CSV data file from Google Adwords API. It is formatted like this: `Keyword;"Monatliches Suchvolumen";Competition;"Suggested Bid"` and has `.csv` file ending. Here an original data sample:

```
+--------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+---------------+
| Keyword                  | Monatliches Suchvolumen | Competition      | Suggested Bid |
+--------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+---------------+
| rechtsschutzversicherung | 110000                  | 0.84808008438954 | 6404121       |
+--------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+---------------+
| rechtsschutz             | 12100                   | 0.7662246934702  | 6050097       |
+--------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+---------------+
```

Then i upload it to Google Drive with `File Upload`. After upload the file is recognized as Google Spreadsheets file - but after opening i have all data in one column, column separation doesn't work.

If after downloading the file from AdWords API i open it in Notepad++, remove `""` and replace `;` with tabs, save the file and then upload it to Google Drive, column separation works and all data is in its correct column. But i can't do it manually - i have too many files.

What should i do to reach automatic column recognition in Google Spreadsheets?

Was trying: played with Google Drive settings, like `Convert uploaded files to Google Docs editor format`, but without success. I thought about the localization settingsdirectly in Google Spreadsheets - but this will not work, because these settings can be edited only after spreadsheets is already created - and here is all data already in one column.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your question, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If to use Google Apps Script is not included in the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your current situation and goal as follows.

- You have a CSV file on your Google Drive.
- CSV data is as follows.

  ```
    Keyword;"Monatliches Suchvolumen";Competition;"Suggested Bid"
    ,
    ,
    ,
  ```
- You want to parse the CSV data and put to the Spreadsheet.

In this case, how about using Google Apps Script? I thought that when Google Apps Script is used, the CSV file on your Google Drive can be retrieved and parsed. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following Google Apps Script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet, and set the variable of `fileId`. And, when you run the function of `myFunction`, the authorization screen is opened. So please authorize the scopes. By this, the script retrieves the CSV data from the CSV file, and parse the CSV data and put to the active sheet.

```
function myFunction() {
  const fileId = "###";  // Please set the file ID of the CSV file on your Google Drive.

  const csv = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob().getDataAsString();
  const values = Utilities.parseCsv(csv, ";");
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### Note:

- When you want to retrieve the CSV data from the CSV file using the filename, you can also use the following script.

  ```
    function myFunction2() {
      const filename = "sample.csv"; // Please set the filename of CSV file on your Google Drive.
      const file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename);
      if (!file.hasNext()) {
        throw new Error(`"${filename}" was not found.`);
      }
      const csv = file.next().getBlob().getDataAsString();
      const values = Utilities.parseCsv(csv, ";");
      const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
    }
  ```
- This is a simple sample script. So please modify this for your actual situation.

#### References:

- [getFileById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid)
- [parseCsv(csv, delimiter)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv,-delimiter)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)